# virtual public inheritance? Need help understanding code

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have question about virtual inheritance.
I'm interested why this code prints 1000 (from class "two") and not 3 (from class "one")

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
protected:
    int number;
public:
    A (int a=0) {number=a;}
};

class one:virtual public A {
public:
    one (int a=3) {number=a;}
    void print()  {cout<<number<<endl;}
};

class two :virtual public A {
public:    
    two (int a=1000) {number =a;}
    void print() { cout<<number<<endl; }
};

class B:public one,public two {
public:
    void print() { cout<<number<<endl; }
};

int main () {
    B A;
    A.print();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base classes are initialised in the order they are declared: `one` then `two`. The virtual inheritance means that they both share the same instance of `A`, so there is only one variable called `number` here.

Initialising `one` assigns 3 to `number` then initialising `two` assigns 1000 to it. So, after initialising the whole object, it ends up with the value 1000.